# Speech Recognizer and/or Recognition Listener doesn't seem to work even though permission have been allowed and app is running with no errors

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-permissions

Speech Recognition Listner and Recognition Intent doesn't seem to be called or initiated at all even though method startListening() and stopListening() are called and RECORD_AUDIO permission was allowed. The code below is where I am utilizing them in the showDialog() method which is been called in a on click listener in the onCreate() part of the class.

```
    private void speakWithVoiceDialog(String shoppingListUserItemName) {
        System.out.println("ACCESSED");
        androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder
                        (ShoppingListUserItemsActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(ShoppingListUserItemsActivity.this).inflate(
                R.layout.voice_input_dialog,
                (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDialogContainerVID)
        );
        builder.setView(view);
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);

        }
            Button cancel_button = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
            Button enter_button = view.findViewById(R.id.enterButton);
            EditText quantityEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_edit_text);
            EditText unitPriceEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.unit_price_edit_text);
            ImageView quantityMicrophone = view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_microphone);
            ImageView unitPriceMicrophone = view.findViewById(R.id.unit_price_microphone);
            final androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            enter_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
//                    QueryUtils.saveDetailsOfShoppingListUserItem(shoppingListUserItemName, EnglishWordsToNumbers.replaceNumbers(String.valueOf(quantityEditText.getText())), unitPriceEditText.getText());


                }
            });
            SpeechRecognizer quantitySpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
            SpeechRecognizer unitPriceSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
            final Intent quantitySpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            quantitySpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            quantitySpeechRecognizerIntent .putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
            final Intent unitPriceRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            // when the users click on the textviews next to the edit texts for hold details, listening starts
            RecognitionListener quantityRecognitionListener = new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {
                System.out.println("@onEndOfSpeech - quantity");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                System.out.println("@onResults - quantity");
                ArrayList<String> data = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                quantityEditText.setText(EnglishWordsToNumbers.replaceNumbers(data.get(0)));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {
                System.out.println("@onPartialResults - quantity");
                ArrayList<String> data = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                quantityEditText.setText(EnglishWordsToNumbers.replaceNumbers(data.get(0)));

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }
        };
            quantitySpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(quantityRecognitionListener);
            quantityMicrophone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                        if(quantityMicrophoneState == 0){
                            quantityMicrophone.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(ShoppingListUserItemsActivity.this, R.color.green), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                            quantitySpeechRecognizer.startListening(quantitySpeechRecognizerIntent);
                            quantityMicrophoneState = 1;
                        }
                        else if(quantityMicrophoneState == 1){
                            quantityMicrophone.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(ShoppingListUserItemsActivity.this, R.color.grey), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                            quantitySpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
                            quantityMicrophoneState = 0;

                        }
                }
            });

            RecognitionListener unitPriceRecognitionListener = new RecognitionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEndOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int i) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                    ArrayList<String> data = bundle.getStringArrayList(unitPriceSpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                    unitPriceEditText.setText(EnglishWordsToNumbers.replaceNumbers(data.get(0)));

                }

                @Override
                public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {
                    ArrayList<String> data = bundle.getStringArrayList(unitPriceSpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                    unitPriceEditText.setText(EnglishWordsToNumbers.replaceNumbers(data.get(0)));

                }

                @Override
                public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }
            };
            unitPriceSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(unitPriceRecognitionListener);

            unitPriceMicrophone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(unitPriceMicrophoneState == 0){
                        unitPriceMicrophone.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(ShoppingListUserItemsActivity.this, R.color.green), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                        unitPriceSpeechRecognizer.startListening(unitPriceRecognizerIntent);
                        unitPriceMicrophoneState = 1;
                    }
                    else if(unitPriceMicrophoneState == 1){
                        unitPriceMicrophone.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(ShoppingListUserItemsActivity.this, R.color.grey), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                        unitPriceSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
                        unitPriceMicrophoneState = 0;

                    }

                }
            });


        if (alertDialog.getWindow() != null) {
            alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        }
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

where I'm calling it

```
                microphoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            showDialog(getString(R.string.delete_shopping_list_item), shoppingListUserItemName, shoppingListName, JSONEditCodes.DELETE_SHOPPING_LIST_ITEM);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and this onClickListener is under a onItemClickListener of a ListView.

I've tried initiating a new Recognition Listener instead of the variables holding the Recognition Listener's for the quantityRecognitionListener and unitPriceRecognitionListener that are set on the respective speech recognizers and both ways it hasn't worked. The android permission is being initiated when denied and granted through the pop-up on my android device, yet I don't even see any methods under the recognition listener occuring(e.g. onPartialResults()).
If needed I can put the code of the whole class. Any ideas/reasons on why its not working?

Comment: I have the same problem with similar code--the listener does not seem to be firing.  No errors, gets into the onClick code from button, creates the RecognizerIntent, EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, and EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, then startListening.  No results, no errors, though listener is implemented with all required methods. ????

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your manifest has not implemented the following line:

```
    <queries>
             <intent>
                    <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
             </intent>
    </queries>
```